# Create an object with key-value pairs from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

Having this input array:

```
const myArray = [{value: "test"}, {value: "abc"}, {value: "xyz"}];
```

the desired result is this: `result = { "value1": "test", "value2": "abc", "value3": "xyz" };`

I have tried to do it but it returns an empty object: `{undefined: ""}`

```
const result = myArray.reduce((agg, item) => {
  agg[item.key] = item.value;
  return agg;
}, {})
```

any ideas?

Comment: Really not clear if you know the key is `value` in each one since you are using `item.value`. If it is known you just need to concatenate `"value" + (index+1)` for the new key

Comment: You really should consider using an array as your value rather than numbered keys `{values: ["test", "abc", "xyz"]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to read the name of the key and use the 3rd parameter of [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the index of currently processed item.

```js
const myArray = [{value: "test"}, {value: "abc"}, {value: "xyz"}];
//the desired result is this: result = { "value1": "test", "value2": "abc", "value3": "xyz" };



const result = myArray.reduce((agg, item, index) => {
  agg[Object.keys(item)[0] + (index + 1)] = item.value;
  return agg;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This question is mostly for the OP, but also relevant to this answer in particular: here, the code dynamically produces a key name based on the input objects' key name, but it also assumes the input key is named `value`. Do you want to assume each input object has a single key named `value` (in which case the dynamic name detection is not needed) or could it vary (in which case the right-hand side of the assignment needs it as well, rather than using `item.value`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like,

```js
const myArray = [{value: "test"}, {value: "abc"}, {value: "xyz"}];

const result = myArray.reduce((agg, item, index) => {

  // append the array index to the key "value"
  agg[Object.keys(item)[0] + (index + 1)] = item[Object.keys(item)[0]];

  return agg;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

The above code will dynamically assign the values to the 'objects' new indexed keys